# How to access edit tag view in Youtrack

Tags: project-management

Near the end of [Youtrack's documentation on tags](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/2017.2/Using-Tags.html) it says that tags can be edited.
However I don't get the listing of tags that is shown as an example and thus no access to the edit button. When viewing a user story I do see the following items listed under the user stories's properties with a similar UI style:

- Voters
- Watchers
- Boards

How can I change the layout of my user stories so tags are added to the list?
Or get access to this window in another way?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 3):

In Youtrack 2020.6.4750, you can open your **Profile**, select **Tab "Tags and Saved Searches"**, switch the filter button "Created by me" at right top side to **"All"**, then you can use the search box next to it or scroll to the entry.

Whether you can edit it depends on your access rights, obviously.

Don't forget to click the "save" button well hidden at the bottom of the page!

Answer (score 1):

In YouTrack 2020.3.533, on the left hand side you'll see a collapsible panel box with sections for Projects, Saved Searches, and Tags. Expand Tags. Hover over the tag you want to change, and select the pencil icon that appears. From there, you can change name, color, permissions, etc.

Comment: In YouTrack 2020.6.4750, no such pencil icon appears.

Comment: @foo I'm on 2020.6.1767 and I have it. Maybe you are using a different UI (YouTrack Lite)?

Comment: Thank you Stealth Rabbi - it wasn't the "lite" mode", but a bug where the UI wasn't loading properly. Your answer works now for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the search screen, in the upper right-hand corner, I had to click "Turn off experimental UI", then the tags lists appeared.